# Is there a way to create synchronization profiles for Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

For example I want to tag some of my browsers as "home browser"s and others as "work browser"s and I want:

- my bookmarks to be synced with all browsers,
- my extensions to be synced only within browsers of the same type (home with home, work with work)

Comment: I take it you can't sign into your home browsers with your personal Google account and your work browsers with your work account and have it just sync things logged into the same account?

Comment: Oops, I misread the question—you want your bookmarks synced with all of them. Well, if nothing else, couldn't you make a “bridge” by having one machine that has two Chrome instances, one signed into your personal account and one signed into your work account, and have that machine sync bookmarks between the two instances?

Answer (score 2):

This is almost the default way that Google profiles act. Just create a separate Gmail account for each place you need. Then click the Chrome window left of your tabs and you'll see a drop down menu. Click **new user** and it will allow you to associate each account with a new Chrome profile. Do this in each browser you want to have this feature and you're good to go.

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en

The one problem with that, which may be why you posted this, is that the bookmarks won't be synced across profiles (work bookmarks and home bookmarks won't sync). If this is what you want then you should use a second sync tool such as [XMarks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xmarks-bookmark-sync/ajpgkpeckebdhofmmjfgcjjiiejpodla?hl=en). Just add that extension to both profiles and create an XMarks account and use that same account on both profiles.

Comment: It's unfortunate that you can't use a single account to do this... I have no need to create and use a google account just for work or for travel (or other use cases outside of home).